# Center text character ☢ vertically and horizontally within a circle (CSS)

Tags: html, css, centering, flexbox

I am trying to center this text character ☢ within a circle. (&#9762;)

While IE 10 displays the text vertically and horizontally centered, both Chrome and Firefox render too much padding at the top.

Any ideas how to fix this? (Flexbox is not a must have)

**HTML**

```
<div class="tl-icon">
<div>☢</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tl-icon {
    align-items: center;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3em;
    height: 3rem;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 3rem;
}
```

See live demo here: http://codepen.io/dash/pen/ZYePWP

Comment: This looks like a case where you should really use an image. You are trying to use text formatting tools of CSS for something that is really an image to be placed inside another image. This is something that graphics programs are for.

Comment: Your codepen demo does not look centered at all, viewing on Chrome 61.0.3163.100 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the inner child is a text which screws with your height.

I added a `line-height` which seems to fix it a bit:

```
.tl-icon div{
  line-height:1px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYePBZ

Comment: Looks ok on FFX34 and on Chrome 39

Answer (score 1):

Target that child div, set it to `inline-block` and change the vertical alignment:

```
.tl-icon div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYpRmm)

Comment: On Firefox 34.0.5 & 35.0

Answer (score 0):

I had to fart about with the dimensions a bit, but this should center vertically and horizontally, so far tested in Chrome, FF and Safari.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbmEWX

Set the parent to

```
  display:table;
```

Child to

```
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
```

Comment: It's not in the centre of the circle

Comment: There might be tiny pixel issues between browers as it is rendering as text. If you want to tweak this you will need some conditional css to target certain browsers. I have done this in the past (it is a feature available in modernizr for example). But it looks very close to me. I also tried standard text and that seems to center accurately. So you could add tiny padding or margins just for Firefox (or others for etc) but this would entail a much more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've done everything correctly with your flexbox CSS.

The issue appears to be with `line-height`. You're using an html entity as text and it looks like `.tl-icon` is inheriting a value for line-height that doesn't work well.

Try adjusting your `line-height`, and using a unitless value for it. This way the line-height will compute to whatever the font size is for the interior element.

```
.tl-icon {
    line-height:.9;
}
```