# How to center a letter in a circle on a <li>

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I've been stuck on this for a while. Please see image attached. I need to make a circle with a centered letter inside it and a line to text aligned centre to the circle. I need help with rest of the code.

```css
.lettercircle {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #009cda;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 28px;
}
#div {
  width: 499px;
  height: 166px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <ul>
    <li> <span>A</span>
      DREAMWEAVER
    </li>
    <li> <span>B</span>
      PHOTOSHOP
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center text character ☢ vertically and horizontally within a circle (CSS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987490/center-text-character-%e2%98%a2-vertically-and-horizontally-within-a-circle-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```css
.lettercircle {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.title {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#div {
  width: 499px;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#div > ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#div > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="lettercircle">A</span>  
      <span class="title">DREAMWEAVER</span>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <span class="lettercircle">B</span>  
      <span class="title">PHOTOSHOP</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good. I need "dreamweaver" and "photoshop" to be capitalize and helvetica

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. How do I add more space between the circle and "dreamweaver" and "photoshop" text? and how come the "dreamweaver" and "photoshop" text doesn't look exactly centred aligned with the circle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to add your class to your spans.

```css
   .lettercircle {
     font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
     background-color: #009cda;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 5px 12px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     font-size: 28px;
   }
   #div {
     width: 499px;
     height: 166px;
   }
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <ul>
    <li> <span class="lettercircle">A</span>
      DREAMWEAVER
    </li>
    <li> <span class="lettercircle">B</span>
      PHOTOSHOP
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by aligned to the circles?

Comment: "Dreamweaver" aligned centre to circle's height