# How to TRULY vertically center text with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

So vertically centering text seemed simple enough with `justify-content` and `align-items` center but when I looked closely I can see that the text isn't truly centered. It has less spacing at the top of the character. I tried to investigate further by searching online and I found this https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align but there must be a simpler solution to this.

Example
https://jsfiddle.net/z7cy487o/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  height: 10%;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 11vh;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;     /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  C
</div>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to me that you would use flexbox to center text. Is there some highly unusual special case that explains why you would do it this way? Or is the issue with the CSS you show without flexbox because, frankly, what you show is very convoluted. It shouldn't be done that way.

Comment: No, for the exact reason in that article you found, there is no other way to _truly_ center text vertical.

Comment: `line-height: 1` can help with consistency of vertical centering

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solution based off a modified version of [Center text character ☢ vertically and horizontally within a circle (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987490/center-text-character-vertically-and-horizontally-within-a-circle-css)
It seems to work with dynamic heights, but as Johannes mentions in the comment of his answer. I believe the solution will only work well with my situation.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  height: 10%;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 11vh;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;     /* align vertical */
}

.char {
  line-height: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.05em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="char">C</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The way you perceive that depends on which characters you are using. I copied your example twice to show different situations:

In the second version I only used the letter "y", which has a descender, i.e. a part that extends below the baseline, to the lower border of the area which is defined as `line-height`. On the other hand, it doesn't go up the whole way, so it seems exactly the opposite of the first version (letter "C") concerning vertical alignment.

In the third version I used both of those letters combined in a word. Here you can see that the different characters/letters together indeed *do* extend across the whole width, so the vertical centering is correct as it is.

Line-height (and in relation to that, vertical alignment of letters) does *not* depend on which letters are used - it always applies to all possible letters/characters, even if they are not used in that particular situation.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
.box
{
    height: 10%;
    width: 400px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 11vh;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
C
</div>

<div class="box">
y
</div>

<div class="box">
Cyborg
</div>
```

Comment: This explains why its not working but do you know how to center a character vertically in the div?

Comment: It would depend which character it is. Basically you can only try different `padding-top'  and `padding-bottom` settings. But even then you have the risk that the character will have a different proportion in different fonts. And it also depends on the font-size and line-height. It's a trial-and-error process which will always only work for one particular situation.